# Why estimateGas return 21001 instead 21000?

Tags: web3js, transactions, fees, gas-estimate

For example

> web3.eth.estimateGas({from: eth.coinbase, to: eth.accounts[1], amount: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})

return 21001, but not 21000, so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue being fixed "in the next release".

see thread here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/1590